# Poner espacio cada 200px

Tags: php, jquery, css

Quiero hacer un div que dentro tiene varios `<ul>` y `<li>` que se rellena automáticamente con mysql y php con un foreach. El `<div>` es infinito y quiero que cada 200px ponga un separador de 50px automáticamente.

¿Esto se puede hacer?

El tamaño del contenido no siempre es el mismo, unas veces ocupara 200 lineas y otras 2.

Realmente me daría igual hacerlo con un `<table>` o de otra forma, lo único que no puedo es sacarlo de el `<div>` contenedor.

Estoy un poco desesperado con este tema :( que llevo 3 meses y no hay forma.

Mil gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: amigo debes tener algun codigo para poder colaborarte

Comment: Hola @x-rw si es que no se si quiera si se puede hacer, no tengo absolutamente nada. bueno si tengo pero solo es un div con un echo de php que lee el campo de mysql.

Comment: seria desastroso probarlo directamente con algun lenguaje de server, primero enfoquemonos en frontend y luego lo unes

Comment: revise otro tema sobre la misma pregunta, tienes buenas respuestas, ninguna de ellas te ayudo al 100%?

Comment: No, ya que el tamaño del contenido es dinámico y no me valen ni las lineas ni la tabla @x-rw así que cambio de planteamiento a ver si así consigo algo

Comment: porque no creas varios div de 200px?

Comment: ¿y como divido el contenido en ellos? @x-rw tengo un hueco de 600px por infinito, pero quiero dividir ese infinito en 200px y los datos son de un único campo de mysql

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco cual es la finalidad de tu pregunta? Realmente no veo cual puede ser la funcionalidad de un div "infinito".

Comment: ¿Esta pregunta fue resuelta?

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo haria es meter una variable y un contador para puder saber cada que se nesecita pero es si usas mysql un ejempo yo se esto para poder dejedesir  una mensaje de una imagen y asi meter un dato bien para el user lo ve  **lo que tu tienes que hacer es un contador que cada 199 meta una variable** 0 o 1 si no sabes como para el codigo

```
// // // // // // // // // Here is to see the chat data----------------->
function cargar_datos(){
        require ("languages/es.php");


$id= $_GET['v']; 

        $data_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * from chat WHERE post=$id ");
    if (mysql_num_rows($data_chat) == 0)
    {
                echo '<br><br><br><center><img src="img/no_messages.png"></img><br>
                '.$Languages_12.'</center>';

    }else{  

    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($data_chat)){
        $user=$res["nombre"];
        $ads=$res["ads"];
        $pads=$res["pads"];
        $men=$res["mensaje"];
        $images=$res["images"];
        $audio=$res["audio"];
        $link=$res["link"];
        $tipo=$res["tipo"];
        $post=$res["post"];
        $time=$res["time"];
        $addressID=$res["id"];
        $timeMessage = time_elapsed($time);



            /////Mensaje
                    $come[0]='';
                    $come[1]="<img src='img/publi2.png' alt=''>";
// // // // // // // // // // // // // // Content type------------------------->
// // // // // // chat
                     $type[0]="<div id='chat' class='message__chat'>
                                        <img class='resize--img' src='img/avatar_default.png' alt=''>               
                                        <p class='message__text'><spam class='message__username'>".$user."</spam>
                                        <spam class='message__username_time'>".$timeMessage."</spam>
                                        <br>".nl2br(bb_parse($res["mensaje"]))."</p>
                               </div>".$come[$ads]."";
// // // // // // imagen        
                    $type[1]="<div id='chat' class='message__img'>
                                    <img class='resize--img' src='img/avatar_default.png' alt=''>               
                                    <p class='message__text'><spam class='message__username'>".$user."</spam>
                                    <spam class='icons_img'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</spam>
                                    <spam class='message__username_time'>".$timeMessage."</spam></p>
                               </div>
                    <div class='message__chat m--user'>
                        <p class='message__text t--user'><img src='uploads/".$post."/".$images."' alt='' width='100%' height='100%'></p>
                    </div>
                        <div class='line'></div>";
// // // // // // audio
                     $type[2]="<div id='chat' class='message__chat'>
                                        <img class='resize--img' src='img/avatar_default.png' alt=''>               
                                        <p class='message__text'><spam class='message__username'>".$user."</spam>
                                        <spam class='message__username_time'>".$timeMessage."</spam><br></p>
                                    <audio controls>
                                      <source src='uploads/".$post."/".$audio."' type='audio/mpeg'>
                                    </audio>
                              </div>";                      
// // // // // // Here are the chat messages    
            echo Hashtag("".$type[$tipo].""); youtube($link); 


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tengo un contador en jquery, lo malo de hacerlo en php es que como el texto ocupa distinta longitud necesito saber los <p> que tiene

Comment: mira pasame el code para ver que puede hacer porque jquery no es mi fuerte